# separate a dataframe into multiple dataframes using specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'season': ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2'],
                   'fruits': ['orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'grapes', 'NaN'],
                   'price': ['40', '80', 'NaN', '40', '30']
                   })

   season fruits  price
0    0    orange  40
1    0    mango   80
2    1    apple   NaN
3    1    grapes  40
4    2    NaN     30
```

I want to group by the season column and generate three different `dataframes`

Expected outcome:

```
df1:
   season fruits  price
0    0    orange  40
1    0    mango   80

df2:
   season fruits  price
2    1    apple   NaN
3    1    grapes  40

df3:
   season fruits  price
4    2    NaN     30
```

I am using `df[df['season']==0]` but I think it is too static

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and a dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs = {f'df{int(k)+1}': g for k,g in df.groupby('season')}
```

output:

```
{'df1':   season  fruits price
 0      0  orange    40
 1      0   mango    80,
 'df2':   season  fruits price
 2      1   apple   NaN
 3      1  grapes    40,
 'df3':   season fruits price
 4      2    NaN    30}
```

Access:

```
dfs['df1']
#   season  fruits price
# 0      0  orange    40
# 1      0   mango    80
```

Or, maybe better, as list:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby('season')]

dfs[0]
#   season  fruits price
# 0      0  orange    40
# 1      0   mango    80
```

Comment: I have always thought that we cannot do anything else than `apply` on a `groupby`. Never thought that you can just iterate on it. Thanks @mozway !

Comment: @pac you can actually do much more ;)

Comment: @mozway can you explain  the code with the list implementation? Also how you access the generated dataframes without everytime to have to indexing. For example for the first dataframe  i execute df1=pd.Dataframe(dfs[0]) but it return me an erro

Comment: this would be `df1 = dfs[0]`, the values are already DataFrames, but honestly, use the container it is bad practice to try to generate variable names automatically

Comment: why is a bad practise?

Comment: Think the question the other way around, what do you gain in having df1, df2, df3,… df1438?  With a container, you know that another piece of code is not going to come modify your variable. It is more explicit.

Comment: yes, I understand. Can you please put some comments on your code? Especially here: g for _,g

Comment: @xavi iteration on `groupby` returns a tuple of the group name and the sub-dataframe. Here we do not care about the group name so we assign it to `_`. We could use any name but this is a convention to indicate that we won't use this variable.